# Why is the derivative of one function equal to the negative of another?

Tags: derivatives

[image]

Could somebody explain to me the answer of d? Why is $h’ = -f$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F(x)=\int_0^x f(y) \, dy$ for $0 \le x \le 3$

Then since $F'(x)=f(x)$ and  $F(x) + h(x)=F(3)$, you get $F'(x)+h'(x)=0$ so $h'(x)=-f(x)$

$f(x)$ is positive when $0<x<2$ so $h'(x)$ is negative, and this means $h(x)$ is decreasing when $0 \le x \le 2$

Comment: You meant $F(x)=\int_0^x$, not $\int_0^3$, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark I did - thank you - now edited

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any intuition to understand this problem apart from the algebra?

Comment: @MINHTO An alternative is to actually find $h(x)$ by doing the piecewise integration